# 403 forbidden - socket.io connection across subdomains with Passport.io + express + socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, passport.js

I have a NodeJS express server at data.domain.com and my AngularJS client lives at subdomain.domain.com. I'm creating session on the server using passport / express. Then my client is attempting to connect to socket.io on the same server. I'm getting 403 (Forbidden) on the socket.io connection.

I'm thinking that this is a cross domain issue. I've enabled CORs on the express server. I'm setting a cookie with the TLD from my server data.domain.com, i.e. the express cookie domain config is .domain.com.

I've checked that my session cookie is being set on the client - 'expressSid' with the TLD .domain.com. Everything works instantly when I comment out the block starting io.set("authorization"...

Everything is running under HTTPS. I'm using RedisStore for session storage.

Passport.io / socket.io config:

```
io.configure(function () { 
   io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']); 
   io.set('polling duration', 10); 
   io.set('log level', 1);

   io.set("authorization", passportSocketIo.authorize({
      cookieParser: express.cookieParser, //or connect.cookieParser
      key:          'expressSid',        //the cookie where express (or connect) stores its session id.
      secret:        expressSecret,  //the session secret to parse the cookie
      store:         sessionStore,      //the session store that express uses
      fail: function(data, accept) {      // *optional* callbacks on success or fail
     accept(null, false);              // second param takes boolean on whether or not to allow handshake
  },
  success: function(data, accept) {
    accept(null, true);
  }
 }));

});
```

Express config:

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    var oneof = false;
    if(req.headers.origin) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    oneof = true;
    }
    if(req.headers['access-control-request-method']) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', req.headers['access-control-request-method']);
    oneof = true;
    }
    if(req.headers['access-control-request-headers']) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', req.headers['access-control-request-headers']);
    oneof = true;
}
if(oneof) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
}

// intercept OPTIONS method
if (oneof && req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
    res.send(200);
}
else {
    next();
}
};

appSecure.configure(function(){

   appSecure.use(allowCrossDomain);
   appSecure.use(express.cookieParser(expressSecret));
   appSecure.use(express.bodyParser());
   appSecure.use(express.methodOverride());
   appSecure.use(org.expressOAuth({onSuccess: '/home', onError: '/oauth/error'}));  // <--- nforce middleware
   appSecure.set('port', port); 
});

appSecure.configure('production', function(){
   appSecure.use(express.errorHandler());
   appSecure.use(express.session({ secret: expressSecret, store: sessionStore, key:'expressSid', cookie: { domain:'.domain.com'}})); 
   appSecure.use(passport.initialize());
   appSecure.use(passport.session());
   appSecure.use(appSecure.router);
   appSecure.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

Comment: I think my problem was old session cookies from earlier development iterations being sent on the socket.io connection request. I cleared cookies in the browser and things seems to be working better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933980/make-a-secure-oauth-api-with-passport-js-and-express-js-node-js/20218939#20218939

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by clearing browser cookies in Chrome.

I did start passing the express secret to cookieParser but I don't think that alone solved the issue. I had several session cookies being passed on the request from earlier iterations. Clearing the cookies from the browser fixed the issue.